# How do I get jQuery UI working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I reference jquery-1.8.3.min.js and jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js in my file, but nothing seems to be working. What is the problem? Here's my code for the tab UI:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" > </script>
</head>

<div id="tabContainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabOne">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabTwo">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabThree">Tab 3<a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="tabOne">
<p> This is the first tab</p>
</div>
<div id="tabTwo">
<p> This is the first tab</p>
</div>
<div id="tabThree">
<p> This is the first tab</p>
</div>

<script typle="text/javascript">
$('#tableContainer').tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you haven't included jQuery ui CSS file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6c9J/1/ - also your mark up is not proper

Comment: Arun is right, you also may want to throw your script inside of [`$(function(){});`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: ... and remember "nothing is working" is not usually enough information to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

From [getting started page of jQuery UI](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/):

> Generally, you'll need to include these three files on any page to use
>   jQuery UI widgets and interactions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themename/jquery-ui.custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
```

You seem to be missing the required CSS file.

Also, you seem to be missing at least the beginning `<body>` tag.